# django cors headers missing in response for requested media and images

Tags: angularjs, django, django-rest-framework, media, django-cors-headers

Developing Django Rest Framework API coupled with Ionic/Angularjs frontend, each operating on different domain.  Using django-cors-headers to take care of cors issues.

My problem is with serving user-uploaded media.  It seems that cors headers are not included in response headers for images served from development django server.

I need this for some canvas-based functionality on front end.

All other responses contain correct cors headers.  Is there a reason that media is exempted?

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If everything OK with nginx, you can write middleware:

```
class MyCorsMiddleware(object):

def process_response(self, request, response):
    response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    response['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT'
    return response
```